# With mocha, how do I run all tests that *don't* have (slow) in the name?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocha.js

I have a load of tests, and some of them have "(slow)" in the name:

[image]

Some of them are slower than the tests marked (slow), but are relied on by other tests and so cannot be skipped. I would just like to skip the ones with (slow) in the name—is that possible?

I'm using Mocha.

Comment: I would like to point out that if one test relies upon another test, then the dependency should be moved to a before() hook, which will be called for the tests in question.  Nesting describe() suites is also beneficial.  For multiple tests on the same thing, I tend to put the slow thing in a promise await'ed on by the before hook, and also await'ed on by the tests.  And then in the tests, I put the code I expect to actually fail (like assert.deepEqual)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me like you are doing it for a page you are loading in a browser to run Mocha. To do this in the browser you can pass these parameters in the URL of the page:

- `grep` which approximately corresponds to the `--grep` option on the command line. This narrows the tests run to those that match the expression passed to `grep`. However, there is currently (even as of 2.0.1) no way to get Mocha to interpret this parameter as a *regular expression*. It is always interpreted as a string. That's why I said "approximately corresponds". `--grep` on the command line is a regular expression but the `grep` parameter passed in a URL is a string.
- `invert` which correspond to the `--invert` option on the command line. This will invert the match performed by `grep` and thus selects the tests that `grep` does not match.

So if you open you page by appending the following string `?grep=(slow)&invert=1` it will run the tests that do not have the string `"(slow)"` in them.

Comment: Using regular expressions is possible from javascript code. For example: `mocha.setup({ui: 'bdd',grep: new RegExp(".*")});mocha.run();`

Comment: Tested as mocha 6.2.2, --grep does take a regex, and negative lookahead did work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918842/895245

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with a combination of two command line switches. Here is the relevant part of the documentation:

`-g, --grep <pattern>      only run tests matching <pattern>
-i, --invert      inverts --grep matches`

Answer (score 4):

Grep accepts a regex pattern, you can do it like this:

```
mocha --grep '^(?!.*\\b\(slow\)\\b)'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mocha --opts mocha.opts --grep "^(?!.*SomeExpression)"
```

I couldn't add parenthesis to the expression - bash / mocha fails. I suggest you to remove the parenthesis and put a tag like @performance in the descriptions and execute mocha with a grep expression like previous one.